# Login Code for Popup is not working

Tags: magento-1.8, login

i am using login code of magento in popup and it not working below is my code

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account') ?>" method="post" id="login-form">
        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>
        <div class="login-popup-content">
                <div class="login-div">
                   <div class="login-txt-div">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="register-link">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">New ? Register</a>
                            </div><!--end of register-link-->
                        </div><!--end of col-md-4-->
                        <div class="col-md-6"> <h2><?php echo $this->__('Login in to Your Account') ?></h2></div>
                        <div class="col-md-3">                       
                            <div class="register-link" style="width: 125px !important;">                            
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">    
                                    <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close                       
                                </a>
                            </div><!--end of register-link-->
                        </div>
                     </div><!--end of row-->
                   </div><!--end of login-txt-div-->

               <div class="login-detail" >
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="uname-detail">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h2>Username</h2>
                            </div><!--end of col-md-4-->
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="email" name="login[username]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getUsername()) ?>" id="email" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" />
                            </div><!--end of col-md-8-->
                        </div><!--end of uname-detail-->
                    </div><!--end of row-->


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="uname-detail">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <h2>Password</h2>
                            </div><!--end of col-md-4-->
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="password" name="login[password]" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" id="pass" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" />
                            </div><!--end of col-md-8-->
                        </div><!--end of uname-detail-->
                    </div><!--end of row-->
                </div>               
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>

                <div class="help-container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">     
                                <div class="help-div">
                                    <span><i class="fa fa-question"></i>Need help?</span>
                                </div><!--end of help-div-->
                            </div><!--end of col-md-3-->
                            <div class="col-md-3">     
                                <div class="login-btn">
                                    <button class="login_bttn" type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Login') ?>" name="send" id="send2"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></span></span></button>
                                </div><!--end of loginbtn-->
                            </div><!--end of col-md-3-->
                            </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayur, Your loggin url is wrong.it should be `<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/login') ?>` Instead of  `<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account') ?>`

Comment: take time to answer don't give answers in hurry

Comment: Yeah but i am not going to LOGGED IN with my current email id by using popup login.